# How To Add Video As Background In Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, video

I Want to add video as background in magento home page.

I used this code but it is not working.

```
<div class="additional-info-2">
    <div id="bgndVideo" data-property="{videoURL:'//youtu.be/z83L-twjEnI', containment:'#bgndVideo', autoPlay:true, mute:true, opacity:1, loop:true, showControls:false, quality:'medium', startAt:0, mute:'true', stopMovieOnBlur:false, addRaster:true}"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <h3>Helping People</h3>
    <a href="{{store url='icons.html'}}">Learn More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide us more detail